# Properly closing window created on a separate thread using ATL

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com, atl

I have a multithreaded application and on certain threads, I'm creating windows using ATL's `CWindowImpl<>`. I have a static method that I'm using as the thread procedure. I need to create a window on the thread, because I need some of my communication with the thread to [be synchronous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/23/9248851.aspx), and `PostThreadMessage()` is expressly asynchronous. When my window receives the `WM_DESTROY` message (handler defined by the `MESSAGE_HANDLER` macro), it calls `PostQuitMessage()`, as shown in this method:

```
LRESULT MyATLWindowClass::OnDestroy(UINT uMsg,
                                    WPARAM wParam,
                                    LPARAM lParam,
                                    BOOL& bHandled) {
  ::PostQuitMessage(0);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using a custom message to the thread using `PostThreadMessage()` to indicate to the thread that it's time to terminate itself. Handling that custom message, I call the `CWindowImpl::DestroyWindow()` method, which does appear to properly destroy the window, as my `OnDestroy` message handler is getting called. However, it doesn't appear that the owning thread ever receives a `WM_QUIT` message for processing. Included below is a simplified version of my thread procedure.

```
unsigned int WINAPI MyATLWindowClass::ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter) {
  // Initialize COM on the thread
  ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

  // Create the window using ATL
  MyATLWindowClass new_window;
  HWND session_window_handle = new_window.Create(
      /* HWND hWndParent */ HWND_MESSAGE,
      /* _U_RECT rect */ CWindow::rcDefault,
      /* LPCTSTR szWindowName */ NULL,
      /* DWORD dwStyle */ NULL,
      /* DWORD dwExStyle */ NULL,
      /* _U_MENUorID MenuOrID */ 0U,
      /* LPVOID lpCreateParam */ NULL);

  // Initialize the message pump on the thread.
  MSG msg;
  ::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

  // Run the message loop
  BOOL get_message_return_value;
  while ((get_message_return_value = ::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if (get_message_return_value == -1) {
      // GetMessage handling logic taken from MSDN documentation
      break;
    } else {
      if (msg.message == WD_SIGNAL_THREAD_SHUTDOWN) {
        // Requested thread shutdown, so destroy the window
        new_window.DestroyWindow();
      } else if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
        // Process the quit message and exit the message loop
        // to terminate the thread
        break;
      } else {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
    }
  }

  // Uninitialize COM on the thread before exiting
  ::CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that it doesn't seem to matter if I call `DestroyWindow()` or if I send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window. The thread's message pump is not receiving WM_QUIT in either case.  Should the owning thread's message pump be receiving such a message? Where is my misunderstanding about how the thread's message pump and the window's message pump interact? Or what am I missing about how ATL's window classes create and manage windows?

Comment: `WM_QUIT` is to terminate the whole app, and you are just destroying your window... Why do you expect `WM_QUIT` to come? It does not have to be there unless you have specific reason. If your thread is here solely for the purpose to host the window, then just monitor `WM_NCDESTROY` on the thread proc and once you processed it for your window, it's good time for the thread to shut down.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `PostQuitMessage()`, that API function should post a `WM_QUIT` message to the thread's message queue, and should be usable on a per-thread basis. Am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: GetMessage returns 0 for the WM_QUIT message, so your while loop terminates without executing the loop body. So you don't need the test for == WM_QUIT

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Aha! That's the piece I was missing. I overlooked that piece in the `GetMessage` docs. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetMessage() never returns WM_QUIT.  That message forces it to return 0 instead, designed to terminate your message loop.

Beware of the considerable hazards of using PostThreadMessage().  It should *never* be used on a thread that also displays windows, like the one you are using.  The issue is that it doesn't take a HWND argument.  So only your message loop can see the message, it won't be delivered to any window with DispatchMessage().  This goes wrong when a modal message loop is entered, the kind that are outside of your control.  Like the modal loop that makes MessageBox work.  Or the one that Windows uses to allow the user to resize a window.  Or the one that DialogBox() uses.  Etcetera.  Always use PostMessage(), use your own message number.

Comment: I'll simply point out here that my window is never, ever, ever shown to the user, and is merely used as a synchronizing convenience for communication between threads. This is the behavior I want. Should this application ever actually begin to draw windows on the screen, this code would need to be refactored anyway. Incidentally, I moved to `PostThreadMessage` because simply sending `WM_CLOSE` to the window (with an appropriate message handler), and waiting for the thread to exit would crash deep in the C runtime. This approach, on the other hand, works.

Comment: Oh, and for those keeping score at home, the application in question is open-source, specifically the IEDriverServer.exe application of the [Selenium project](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/). If anyone wants to take a crack at fixing my apparent incompetence at Windows programming, be my guest. [Patches gratefully accepted](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Some late additional thoughts. You could probably safely terminate your message loop as soon as you have discovered `WD_SIGNAL_THREAD_SHUTDOWN`:

```
  if (msg.message == WD_SIGNAL_THREAD_SHUTDOWN) {
    // Requested thread shutdown, so destroy the window
    new_window.DestroyWindow();
    break; // exit the message loop
  }
```

`DestroyWindow` is a synchronous call, the window will be fully destroyed before it returns and you can exit the loop. So, posting WM_QUIT would be redundant.

Also, you could use [message-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only) window, if the windows is invisible and its only purpose is to process messages.